# Replacement for ServerSwitcher addon (Firefox)

Tags: gratis, firefox

With v57 in November, a bunch of Firefox addons will stop working due to the drop of support for the addon API (switch to WebExtensions). Because of that, and the API still not being "stable", many addon devs announced to no longer support Firefox. Some of my addons will be available after that, for some others I found replacements (see [my list here](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/db7c7d4243283ca84b3abd8b94114e2e)). For others I'm still looking. One of them is:

**[Server Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/server-switcher/)** adds a little icon inside the address bar. For sites you can configure "URL pairs", it shows up and lets you, per click, switch between the very same page on your development and your production server. Say you're on `http://dev.example.com/some/page`, a single click could bring you to `https://prod.example.com/some/page`.

[image: ServerSwitcher] [image: ServerSwitcher]
<sup>*Server Switcher* (source: [AMO](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/db7c7d4243283ca84b3abd8b94114e2e))</sup>

As you can see, even the icon switches to indicate which end you are on.

**Is there a similar addon that works with Firefox 57+** (i.e. is a web extension)?

- free (gratis, open-source preferred)
- lets me configure server pairs to switch between (as described above)
- indicates with its icon which end I'm on (preferred, not a must)
- easily accessible and visible (address bar would be the preferred place, but other easily accessible and visible locations would do as well)

Comment: I didn't find exactly what you want.  But if you are familiar with coding Web Extensions, you should be able to modify the ***Add HTTPS*** Web Extension (https://github.com/sanspace/add-https) to do what you want.  It satisfies your requirements, except the second one.  It can only switch between the HTTP and HTTPS version of the same site.  You would have to modify it to switch between two different servers.

Comment: Thanks, @RockPaperLizard – but no, I'm not experienced with that :(